# C# Datagridview Cell Value Showing or Hiding Other Value

Tags: c#, windows, datagridview, desktop

What I am trying to do is in each row if the datagridview there is a Cell (2) called Serial. If the serial contains the word Meco or Melco it will show the other cell values (Siding / Roof & Trim) but if it DOES NOT contain Meco Or Melco then it hides that values of Siding & Trim I tried the following and alot of other things.

```
 string s = "MECO";

        if (s.Contains("MECO") == true)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns[22].Visible = true; // Siding
            dataGridView1.Columns[23].Visible = true; // Roof
            dataGridView1.Columns[24].Visible = true; // Trim
            Console.WriteLine("Word found!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Word not found!");
            dataGridView1.Columns[22].Visible = false; // Siding
            dataGridView1.Columns[23].Visible = true; // Roof
            dataGridView1.Columns[24].Visible = false; // Trim
        }
```

However I have not got anything to work.. can someone please help this is basically for ordering metal for metal barns and non metal barns only showing the roof color.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are asking. It sounds like you want to have “different” columns showing depending on if a rows cell value contains “Meco” … ? … Two different rows CAN NOT contain “different” columns. All rows must have the same columns. Sorry if I missed something.

Comment: Do you need to hide CELLS or COLUMNS? In your code you hiding COLUMNS.

Comment: @DotNet Developer … How would you hide a single cell in a grid?

Comment: That depends on what we mean by "hide". For example not painting a certain cell also can mean "hide".

Comment: You can certainly cover up or not show any data in a cell, however, the “CELL” still exists and always will. I could be mistaken about this; however, I am not going to get into semantics as to what “hide” means. The OP should make it clear about what they are asking.

Comment: The OP is saying `show the other cell values` => not a column or cell, `it hides that values of Siding & Trim` => not a column or cell. But in code he is trying to hide entire column. That's why I am trying to clarify what he wants.

Comment: I think I would have one column be a combo box of "metal" "non metal" and then other columns be a combo box of either "some colors" or "not applicable" if metal is/is not chosen. This is a parent/child related data scenario; dataset, relation, parent table materials, child table colors or NA for a material, two combos, colors bound to the data relation on the bindingsource of the materials, cell always visible and showing either a color for metal or "n/a for wood" if wood is the chosen material etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say

> If the serial contains the word Meco or Melco it will show the other cell values, but if it DOES NOT contain Meco Or Melco then it hides that values

At User Interface level to hide and show cell VALUES you can handle CellPaint event of DataGridView and omit painting of cell content. Here is an Example,

```
private void DataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex == dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
    {
        return;
    }
    var s = dataGridView1[serialDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Index, e.RowIndex].Value as string;
    if (s.Contains("MECO") || s.Contains("MELCO"))
    {
        var flag1 = e.ColumnIndex == sidingDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Index;
        var flag2 = e.ColumnIndex == trimDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Index;
        if (flag1 || flag2)
        {
            e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.Background | DataGridViewPaintParts.Border);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

However, to make the interface more comprehensive for the users, you can also draw something else instead of cell's actual content to mean hidden value. What to draw is up to you.

---

**Edit**

According to the image file you provided, Serial column is at 1, Siding column is 2, Trim column is 4. So the above code should be

```
private void DataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex == dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
    {
        return;
    }
    var s = dataGridView1[1, e.RowIndex].Value as string;
    if (!(s.Contains("MECO") || s.Contains("MELCO")))
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 2 || e.ColumnIndex == 4)
        {
            e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.Background | DataGridViewPaintParts.Border);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I apologize for the confusion - yes i was trying to hide the column/cell from the code as a example i know the column/cell can not be hidden without the entire row..  All i need it to do is like say for instance it says MECO or MELCO all data text can be seen but if it does not say meco or melco it will black out the siding / trim text maybe paint the bg of the cell black just where the text is not seen.

Comment: This is a datagridview that populates using MySql from a website backend. So the datagridview is empty as well as columns etc...and is auto populated from when the form is loaded calling from the MySql and forming the datagridview

Comment: https://ibb.co/WxbhRLX  here is a link to what i am trying to do - the black represents a serial without melco / meco and not showing the text in that cell

Comment: The code I provided answers all of your requirements.

Comment: on the serialDataGridViewTextBoxColumn I am erroring out because the column is not actually there until you load the program - i can't get the index to read

Comment: See the Edit. I modified the code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help I appreciate it..DotNet Developer appreciate it

Comment: Hello Jarson,

this is your first answer. It does not add anything to the discussion and might be misleading for other People. I suggest to mark the correct answer isntead and/or use the upvote functionality to the left of the answers. Lg, Julian

Comment: The "Answer" is no answer to the original question but a comment/thank you on other peoples answer. Please use the Upvote functionality and mark the best/correct answer as correct answer. Additional feedback/questions&remarks can be given as a comment rather than as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider a couple of things in relation to using the grids `CellPainting` event to accomplish this. For starters, the `CellPainting` event will fire many-many times, like when the grid gets focus or the user moves the cursor over some cells.

My point is… that AFTER the grid is loaded with data… then checking the “Serial” cell again… when the grid gets focus or the user moves the cursor over certain cells… is clearly unnecessary. If you put a debug statement in the cell paint event when the cells are colored, you will see that the code obligingly re-paints the cells many times over when NOTHING has changed.

Next, if the user does “change” a “Serial” cells value after the data has been loaded, then the coloring of the “Siding” and “Trim” cells will not necessarily reflect the proper coloring. You will have to click on the “Siding” and “Trim” cells for the coloring changes to take place. The reason for this is that when the “Serial” cells value changes, the `CellPaint` event will fire… but `e.ColumnIndex` will not be equal to the index of the “Siding” or “Trim” indexes… and those cells will NOT get properly colored.

Given all this, I suggest a different strategy… Instead of using the grids `CellPainting` event for this, I suggest you do this coloring in your code simply to avoid the code executing more than needed. Then use the grids `CellValueChanged` event to change the coloring when a “Serial” cells value is changed. Then we can rest a little easier knowing that the code will never be called unnecessarily.

To help I suggest you create a method that takes a `DataGridViewRow` and colors the cells as needed. Then we could use this method to color the cells when the “Serial” cells value change in addition to the method we create to loop through all the rows in the grid and color each row. This basic `ColorCells` method may look something like….

```
private void ColorCells(DataGridViewRow row) {
  if (row.Cells["Serial"].Value != null) {
    string serialString = row.Cells["Serial"].Value.ToString();
    if (serialString.Contains("MECO") || serialString.Contains("MELCO")) {
      row.Cells["Siding"].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
      row.Cells["Trim"].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
    else {
      row.Cells["Siding"].Style.BackColor = Color.Black;
      row.Cells["Trim"].Style.BackColor = Color.Black;
    }
  }
}
```

Next, the `ColorAllCells` method that we need to call only ONCE AFTER the data is loaded into the grid…

```
private void ColorAllCells() {
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
    ColorCells(row);
  }
}
```

And finally, the grids `CellValueChanged` event to color the cells when a “Serial” cell changes.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Serial") {
    ColorCells(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]);
  }
}
```

I hope this makes sense.